# How to make a default login keyring and use it with libsecret

Tags: login, git, gnome-keyring

I installed libsecret  with git in a docker ubuntu environment.

```
sudo apt-get install libsecret-1-0 libsecret-1-dev
cd /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret
sudo make
git config --global credential.helper /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret
```

I tested the crendential manager with:

```
echo -e "protocol=https\nhost=www.server.com\nusername=bla\npassword=shit\n" | /usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret/git-credential-libsecret store
```

> `No such interface ?org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection? on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login`

How do I make a default login keyring (without a desktop manager, user=root (docker), password=root) and make it unlock when logged in?

Answer (score 1):

Install `gnome-keyring`.

On Debian 10 buster I was getting similar error:

```
 ** (process:12939): CRITICAL **: 12:15:04.448: lookup failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.secrets was not provided by any .service files
```

untill I installed the `gnome-keyring` package (apt-get install gnome-keyring). I hope this solves your problem.